# HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported error

Tags: php, http, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use `file_get_contents()` to get the response from a server and this error was encountered. Could someone tell me what is the reason and how to fix it? The portion of the code is:

```
$api = "http://smpp5.routesms.com:8080/bulksms/sendsms?username=$username&password=$password&source=$source&destination=$destin&dlr=$dlr&type=$type&message=$message";
$resp = file_get_contents($api);
```

The server responded correctly while I pasted the url in the browser.
I learned that this is caused by the server rejecting the client's HTTP version, but I have no idea why that is happening in my case.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am receiving the same error while using 'curl' too.

Comment: Try replacing your '$' with '%24'. It's probably not what's causing your issue, but you should properly urlencode your characters.

Comment: the `$` is actually for the variable. And I've found what caused the error, and it's urlencoding. I didn't notice it earlier bcos the script was working earlier, and I'd missed the function after a bit of editing. Thanks to all the folks who tried to help...and indeed your responses where informational.

Comment: Can you post the working code properly?

Comment: @Prakash Check my own answer.

Comment: @shyam I still got some error, but found the solution. check my answer

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the problem, and it was a simple coding error -- missing url encoding.

The reason I didn't notice it at first was because the code was ok before I did some editing, and I'd missed out the `urlencode()` function before calling the server, which caused a space in the url.

This does seem to be the reason this error occurs for most people. So if you encounter this, use `urlencode()` on all variables which may contain white space in it's value used as URL parameters. So in the case in my question the fixed code will look like:

```
$api = "http://smpp5.routesms.com:8080/bulksms/sendsms?username=$username&password=$password&source=$source&destination=$destin&dlr=$dlr&type=$type&message=" . urlencode($message);
$resp = file_get_contents($api);
```

Also, thanks for all of your time and responses, those were informational.

Comment: I had a url given, and hadn't swapped spaces in the latter part of it. Did so and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

You could [create a stream context](http://php.net/stream_context_create) with the HTTP version set to 1.0 and use that context with `file_get_contents`:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'protocol_version' => '1.0',
        'method' => 'GET'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$api = "http://smpp5.routesms.com:8080/bulksms/sendsms?username=$username&password=$password&source=$source&destination=$destin&dlr=$dlr&type=$type&message=$message";
$resp = file_get_contents($api, false, $context);
```

By the way: Don’t forget to escape your URI argument values properly with `urlencode`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and in my case the culprit was an errant newline/CRLF character at the end of the request URL, which does not get caught by `urlencode()` (or maybe it does encode it but it still causes the server to produce the error). Once I found the problem the requests began to work again, even without the stream context options.

Hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Can you sniff what's happening on the wire? Seeing the format of the HTTP request as it goes out on the wire would help a lot.

Without seeing that, my best guess would be that the server isn't well-implemented, and is rejecting a HTTP/1.1 request. Try setting `--http1.0` on Curl and seeing what happens...

Comment: could you please tell me how to see the format of the HTTP request..?

Comment: You can't do so with file_get_contents. It's an extremely braindead fetch method that gives you no control over how the HTTP request is made. No headers are returned, and you cannot do anything but a simple 'GET'. To get headers and/or do other HTTP request methods, you'll have to use CURL

Answer (score 0):

Some time we still get error with

```
file_get_contents($api);
```

in that case, try this:

```
fopen($api,"r");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this same issue..
later i found that while retrieving the results from mysql, Limit $count ,
$count was -ve. fixing that the url worked fine.
There is some problem in url only, and its not a file_get_contents or http version issue..