# cURL request giving me 505 http code.What to do

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-505

I was not getting the xml response which I was supposed to get when I excecuted the curl. But when curl getinfo, I'm getting the response code 505.

```
$url='http://test/paynetz/epi/fts?login=160&pass=Test@123&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=NSE&amt=50&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=TkFWSU4%3d&txnid='.$string
     .'&date='.$date

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $auth = curl_exec($curl);
$response = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is what I get

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://test/paynetz/epi/fts?login=160&pass=Test@123&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=NSE&amt=50&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=TkFWSU4%3d&txnid=56482&date=28/04/2014 22:24:53&custacc=1234567890&udf1=ajeesh&udf2=ajeesh@fethr.com&udf3=9400429941&udf4=arrackaparmabilhouse&ru
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 505
    [header_size] => 126
    [request_size] => 333
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.451817
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000152
    [connect_time] => 0.224945
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.225027
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.451794
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Why am I getting the curl response?

Comment: Could you provide var_dump() of $curl->read() ?

Comment: How to do this.Can u tell that.So that  can test

Comment: Also take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757404/http-request-failed-http-1-1-505-http-version-not-supported-error.

Comment: print_r($curl->read());

Comment: @ValeryStatichny Im getting blank page

Comment: Thank you much,I could get the response with the link of question you gave :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

505 means HTTP version not supported, so I'm assuming CURL is trying to make the request using  an HTTP version that is not supported by the other service. 
On your code try to see if you can tweak the HTTP version to 1.0 and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Error 505 means that the server doesn't understand the HTTP version you're using. So just changing the HTTP version you're using could solve the problem for you.

Try using an older HTTP version, using `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`.

If that doesn't solve your problem, try looking at this question: [HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757404/http-request-failed-http-1-1-505-http-version-not-supported-error)