# Unable to get JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json

This is my PHP code: (name of the file is getname.php)

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['p']; //supplied as getname.php?p=easy+is+his+name

$link = 'http://api.genius.com/search?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&q='.$query;
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->response->hits[0]->result->title;
?>
```

When I'm running this code, the error is like,

> file_get_contents(http://api.genius.com/search?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&q=easy is his name): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported -- at line 5

And when I write the code as,

```
<?php
$link = 'http://api.genius.com/search?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&q=easy+is+his+name';
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->response->hits[0]->result->title;
?>
```

, the expected results are shown. Why is it so?

Comment: Where is `$obj` output? or share your `access_token` to see output.

Comment: You're asking why you can't have spaces in URL's ?

Comment: fyi: you can do `"url?q=" . urlencode($query);`

Comment: Also, you could try to use curl instead. You can configure it more easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)

Comment: So now you have the URL `http://api.genius.com/search?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&q=getname.php?p=easy+is+his+name`, which doesn't really seem right either ?

Comment: @adeneo The name of the file is getname.php

Comment: According to your edited code, you now have an URL with two questionmarks and other strangeness. It's as easy as supplying a valid URL, and you won't get 505 server errors back

Comment: urlencode() is working well

Comment: Genius.com has an odd API.  Likely susceptible to injection attacks based on the URL format. (instead of getname.php, what if I requested getSecretInfo.php). It could still be secure, but a reason to keep standards in mind for API's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757404/http-request-failed-http-1-1-505-http-version-not-supported-error)

Comment: @KyleWiering thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected:

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['p']; //supplied as getname.php?p=easy+is+his+name

$link = 'http://api.genius.com/search?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&q='.urlencode($query);
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->response->hits[0]->result->title;
?>
```