# PHP Curl returns 403 on server but works on local

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

An API call works on the local, but returns 403 on the live server. This api call requires an API key to be passed by post. The cURL code I tried was as below

```
$header = array("cache-control: no-cache","Content-Type: application/json");
$url = "https://accept.paymobsolutions.com/api/auth/tokens"
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The response it gave on the server is as below

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried it with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
```

And got the same response. Also tried on another server and got the same response. But I got the correct response on an AWS server.

The response I got with the verbose on for debugging on server and local is shown below:

Left is server and right is local.
[image]

How do I fix this cURL code to run on the server?

Comment: What headers do you send?

Comment: $header = array("cache-control: no-cache","Content-Type: application/json").. It's a simple API call.

Comment: Headers look okay. What's there in `$url`? Is the site https?

Comment: It might be something to do with certificates you need to send

Comment: I had also tried with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to true. It gave the same response. Nothing wrong with certificates or ssl. The site is https as its a payment gateway

Comment: @vivek_23 I think its because the cURL uses HTTP/2 instead of HTTP/1.1. Do you know how to force cURL to use HTTP/1.1?

Comment: Not really sure what could be the issue with this info, does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894411/how-to-force-curl-to-ask-for-http-1-1-or-maybe-theres-another-issue-not-sure ?

Comment: Did you get an answer @SaeeshTendulkar ?

Comment: @AdamJones No. But the problem was with the server. It was accepting requests from my local and not server because of the country from which request is sent from