# Jmeter:- HTTP Request :Response code: 505

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter for HTTP Request - I am getting Error as Response code: 505
Response message: HTTP Version Not Supported.  Please let  me know the Reason?

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-04-10 18:02:51 IST
Load time: 9
Connect Time: 7
Latency: 9
Size in bytes: 126
Sent bytes:2753
Headers size in bytes: 126
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 505
Response message: HTTP Version Not Supported

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 12:32:05 GMT
Connection: close


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Comment: you need to provide more details about your request and server you are sending to

Comment: It would also help us to supply with code. All that we're looking at is a server response, and we really have no idea what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably hitting a server using either HTTP 1.0 or HTTP 2.

You need to look at server logs to be sure.

Another possibility is missing information in your request so you need to show it:

- [HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757404/http-request-failed-http-1-1-505-http-version-not-supported-error/2770927#2770927)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) and explicitly specify [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) version like:

[image: JMeter HTTP Raw Request Protocol]

Result of the HTTP Raw Request sampler can be normally examined using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image: JMeter View Results Tree HTTP Raw Request]

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Http Raw Request]